# Who updates pip package versions?

Tags: python, pip, package-managers

I was having problems with one package not doing what I read in it's documentation, until I noticed that pip installed a outdated version.

On the pip package page it would seem like it was last update 2014, but when I installed, the package files were versioned mid 2013.

How does updating pip packages work and who should be doing it? The project maintainer (on github, or on pip pages?)?

Comment: The project maintainer is responsible for updating the PyPI project page. It could be they made an error when uploading. Can you give us an example project so we can see what you are talking about?

Comment: The other possibility is that the "old" version is the latest one that is compatible with your version of python.

Comment: @SteveBarnes I installed from pip by checking out the latest git commit (which is newer by roughly a year) - presumably this would still check requirements from the settings.py and fail if the version was incompatible?

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's a generic question, so I'm not intending to cast a bad light on any maintainers' efforts only to illustrate the point, unless crucial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All packages that can be downloaded with PIP are actually hosted on the [Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi). The Python organization collaborates with project maintainers to host the projects.

Comment: Reading between the lines here: If I'd want the package to get updated, it's the maintainer I should be contacting?

Comment: Yes, what package is it that you need?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with having outdated packages on pip that do not align with the documentation and current state on github can be really annoying. Despite that you did not ask for a workaround I would like to contribute one in case that other users might land on this page looking for such.

First uninstall the `package` you installed via `pip` before:

```
pip uninstall package
```

Next install the latest version directly from the `github repo`:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/user/package.git
```

The cool thing about this is that you can still manage your packages with pip but your not limited by what version is available on the Python Package Index.